# XSL code cannot display image

Tags: xslt, arcgis

I am using `arcgis` and I am trying to create an XSL template to configure my HTML PopUp to display attributes of a certain location. My problem is I cannot get the images to be displayed. I've tried using both codes below, but they don't work. The first one displays an empty frame while the second one displays `<img src="E:\Pictures\Lakes\lake1.jpg">`.

Can anyone help, please?

First version:

```
<xsl:when test="FieldName[starts-with(., 'Picture')]">
  <img width="350" height="210">
    <xsl:attribute name="src"><xsl:value-of select="FieldValue" disable-output-escaping="yes"/></xsl:attribute>
  </img>
</xsl:when>
```

Second version:

```
<xsl:when test="FieldName[starts-with(., 'Picture')]">
  <xsl:variable name="imageURL" select="FieldValue"/>
  <p><img border="0" src="{$imageURL}" width="355" height="272"></img></p>
</xsl:when>
```

Comment: How does the input XML look like? Apart from that, remember that some browsers (like FireFox) do not support `disable-output-escaping="yes"`. It's a bug that these [#*/#+* "programmers" of Mozilla didn't fix since 2001](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=98168).

Comment: @zx485, so which XSLT processor exactly supports `disable-output-escaping` in attribute values (`<xsl:attribute name="src"><xsl:value-of select="FieldValue" disable-output-escaping="yes"/></xsl:attribute>`)?

Comment: @zx485 Thank you very much sir for your reply. But my task is sorta aborted, so so it's okay.